# How to import Pandas DF to Mysql without sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am using these modules to connect with MySQL DB.

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors
```

I am trying to figure a way to import the data in pandas DF to MySQL. Usually what I do is

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO accounts (email, name) VALUES (%s, %s)',
                               (email, name,))
mysql.connection.commit()
```

to insert data to MySQL.

But now I need to a Pandas DF to be uploaded to MySQL. My excel file has columns "email" and "name" and I convert it into pandas DF using `pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', index_col=0)` but how can I upload it to MySQL?

Answer (score -2):

Use the `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql` method described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

Try something like:

```python
import pandas as pd 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 

conn = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://root:password@localhost:3306/dbname?charset=utf8') 
df = pd.read_csv('order_info_utf.csv',names = ['user_id','ispaid','price','paidtime']) 
df.head() 
pd.io.sql.to_sql(df,'tablename',con=conn,schema='orders',if_exists = 'replace')
```

Comment: How to do without sqlalchemy?

Comment: @derikS4M1 an non recommended option is downgrade pandas to 0.14. There the to_sql() method accepts the connector from MySQLdb.

Comment: BTW why you don't want to use SQLAlchemy?